# Mongoose: Find subdocument from Mixed Type and update

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to Update and delete sub document. The structure of document as follows,

```
   {
  "projectId": "12345-service-request",
  "projectVersion": [{
    "version":"1",
    "localConfig": [{
      "port": "3003",
      "mongoURI": "mongodb://localhost:27017/serviceRequest",
      "MQ": "RMQ",
      "logLevel": "2",
      "version": "1.1",
      "created": "03-06-2018 03:11:00 PM",
      "active": "N"
    },
    {
      "port": "3004",
      "mongoURI": "mongodb://localhost:27017/serviceRequest",
      "MQ": "IMQ",
      "logLevel": "1",
      "version": "1.2",
      "created": "07-06-2018 03:11:00 PM",
      "active": "Y"
    }]    
  }]
}
```

The fields in **"localConfig"** are not same, they are different as per project.
So I have created schema using **Schema.Types.Mixed** for this as below,

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.set('debug', true);
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const projectVersion = new Schema({ 
    version: {type:String, required: true},
    cloudParams: [String],
    localConfig: [{type:Schema.Types.Mixed}]    // Mixed Type schema
});

const projectConfig = new Schema({
    projectId : {type:String, required: true},
    projectVersion : [projectVersion]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("ProjectConfig", projectConfig);
```

Now, I am trying to find subdocument using condition,

```
projectId = 12345-service-request and
projectVersion.localConfig.version = 1.2
```

But is returns complete document.
Code to find sub document using `$ and $elemMatch`,

```
    let projectId = '12345-service-request';
    let version = '1.2'
    // Using $
    ProjectConfig.findOne({'projectId' : projectId,'projectVersion.localConfig.version' : version },
        { 'projectVersion.$' : 1 }).exec(function(err,projectConfig){
console.log("Result : "+JSON.stringify(projectConfig)); 
        });
```

and

```
ProjectConfig.find({'projectId' : projectId,'projectVersion.localConfig.version' : version } , 
    { 'projectVersion.localConfig' : { $elemMatch : { version : version } } }).exec(function(err,projectConfig){
        console.log("Result : "+JSON.stringify(projectConfig));        
});
```

I am missing something or is there any other way to find subdocument from Mixed type.

Comment: You cannot use `$elemMatch` projection for nested arrays... You need to find some other way to this... May be aggregation